# Is it ok to perform transfer learning with a base model for face recognition to perform one-shot learning for object classification?

Tags: object-recognition, transfer-learning, one-shot-learning, deep-face, open-face

I am trying to create a model that is using a *one-shot learning* approach for a classification task. We do this because we do not have a lot of data and it also seems like a good way to learn this approach (it is going to be a university project). The task would be to classify objects, probably from drone/satellite image (of course zoomed one).

My question is, do you think it would be ok to use a model for face recognition, such as [DeepFace](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eranzato/publications/taigman_cvpr14.pdf) or [OpenFace](http://elijah.cs.cmu.edu/DOCS/CMU-CS-16-118.pdf), and, using transfer learning, retrain it on my classes?